# how do i use the same hotkey in different if statements

Tags: autohotkey

My Code is below.Whenever I try to run it I get an error saying I'm using duplicate hotkeys when in practice they would never interfere with each other. How do I get around this?

"Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.". So I guess need to explain my code.. It's extremely simple I have a state variable that is changed by pressing the arrow keys, then I have if statements that checks what the state is. If I press numpad1 when state = "up" the script should type "A", if the state = "right" it would print I. However I'm getting an error since I used the same hotkey multiple times in my different if statements.

```
state := "none"
UP::
state := "up"
Right::
state := "right"
DOWN::
state := "down"
LEFT::
state := "left"

if (state = "up"){
Numpad1::
Send A
Return
Numpad2::
Send B
Return
Numpad3::
Send C
Return
Numpad4::
Send D
Return
Numpad6::
Send E
Return
Numpad7::
Send F
Return
Numpad8::
Send G
Return
Numpad9::
Send H
Return
}

if (sate = "right"){
Numpad1::
Send I
Return
Numpad2::
Send J
Return
Numpad3::
Send K
Return
Numpad4::
Send L
Return
Numpad6::
Send M
Return
Numpad7::
Send N
Return
Numpad8::
Send O
Return
Numpad9::
Send P
Return
}

if (state = "down"){
Numpad1::
Send Q
Return
Numpad2::
Send R
Return
Numpad3::
Send S
Return
Numpad4::
Send T
Return
Numpad6::
Send U
Return
Numpad7::
Send V
Return
Numpad8::
Send W
Return
Numpad9::
Send X
Return
}

if (state = "left"){
Numpad1::
Send Y
Return
Numpad2::
Send Z
Return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use AHK_L, you can use #IF with multiple definitions of the same hotkey. WARNING this does NOT work with the regular AHK version.

Here is an example.
You set the variables by typing none\ right\ or left\ .
Depending on the variable setting your Tab key will either send NORMAL, LEFT or RIGHT.

```
#SingleInstance Force

Tab::Send, NORMAL

#if (state = "left")
    Tab::Send, LEFT
#if ; End #if (state = "left")

#if (state = "right")
    Tab::Send, RIGHT
#if ; End #if (state = "right")

:*:right\::
    state := "right"
Return

:*:left\::
    state := "left"
Return

:*:none\::
    state := "none"
Return
```

Alternatively, with the normal AHK, you define ONE hotkey and place IF statements inside the hotkeys to change the behaviour based on the state variable.